# How to deploy Provider SQLOLEDB.1 on windows 2008 R2 64-bit

Tags: sql-server-2008, vb6

In my VB6 application, I connect to the SQL Server 2008 R2 using Provider SQLOLEDB.1.
This is not supporting on windows 2008 R2 64-bit. How to deploy "SQLOLEDB.1" provider on windows 2008 R2 64-bit.

Comment: Is your VB6 application 64-bit? If not, why do you need the 64-bit provider?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like downloading and registering Sqloledb.dll, might work.

See here: [Installing the OLE DB Provider for SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa198252%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) 
and the middle of this [page](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15748), where the ASOLEDB9.msi packages are (32 and 64 bit versions). Those packages will install the sqloledb provider.